# Shorthand if statement for property initialization in Javascript

Tags: javascript, validation, jshint, shorthand-if

To make my code cleaner I do the following in a javascript file:

```
var _weight;

function getWeight(){
    _weight || InitializeWeight();

    // do some stuff

    return _weight;
}

function InitializeWeight(){
    _weight = 3;
}
```

JSHint throws an error on shorthand statements like these *"_weight || InitializeWeight()"*:

> Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.

So I check if it is undefined, call this method.

Is this realy wrong? It works perfectly.

How do I write this statement without having JSHint throw up on me?

Comment: did you mean to put `_weight = _weight || InitializeWeight()` ?

Comment: Why are you writing shorthand like that in your code. Spend the couple extra characters and use an `if` statement. Let minifiers handle the shorthand.

Comment: @Dendromaniac: He's short circuiting the initialization function. Doing that assignment would break the functionality unless he changed the function.

Comment: @Dendromaniac, I've tried that, it doesn't work

Comment: Those are not "shorthand statements" those are expressions. And running an expression without using its result looks suspiciously (and in this particular case ugly)

Comment: @zerkms: thank you, I didn't know those are called expressions, now I do. Why does it look suspicious and why ugly, I think it looks nice :)

Comment: An expression returns a result. Running an expression and not using its result is suspicious. If you see the following line: `1 + 2;` in your JS code, what would be your first thought?

Comment: 3. But I need more characters in my comment.

Comment: Your code is valid Javascript. JSHint is warning about it because it looks suspicious to write a boolean expression without using its value.

Comment: JSHint doesn't know that `InitializeWeight()` is being called just for its side effect. Most of the time, if you write a statement like that, it's because you forgot to put the assignment in. The purpose of tools like JSHint and JSLint is to help you find these types of mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`expr`](http://jshint.com/docs/options/#expr) option:

```
/*jshint expr: true */

var _weight;

function getWeight(){
    _weight || InitializeWeight();

    // do some stuff

    return _weight;
}

function InitializeWeight(){
    _weight = 3;
}
```